# Exporting my 3D Planet

Tags: export, graphics3d, textures

Beginning with a picture of the surface of an imaginary planet, I can texture-map this onto a sphere:

```
surface = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ESGy.png"];
plot = SphericalPlot3D[1, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
       TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({10 #5, (1 - #4) - 0.1} &), 
       PlotStyle->{Opacity[1], Directive[Texture[surface]],Lighting->"Neutral"}, 
       Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

My planet can be rotated, turned into an animated .gif, and looks like a fine place to live. Now I want to share my planet with a friend, who has some nice 3D modeling software. He can accept many different formats. So I export my planet in several different ways:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.dxf", plot];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.lwo", plot];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.wrl", plot];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.3ds", plot];
```

but when I read them back in, my planet has become barren:

```
 {Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.dxf"], 
  Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.lwo"], 
  Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.wrl"], 
  Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testSphere.3ds"]}
```

[image]

My questions are: how can I (correctly) export my planet? Is there some other graphics format I should be using? Is there some trick to making the export work?

Comment: Before moving any further, have you been able to check whether it was the export step, the import step, or both that are malfunctioning? In other words, can MMA import a textured 3D object correctly in any of those formats? Also, have you tried opening any of  your exported files in another program to see if the texture has actually been retained?

Comment: @MarcoB -- unfortunately, I don't have any other 3D editing programs (that I know of). I believe it is the texture-step that is causing the problems, though I don't know if it's the import or export where it fails. I would be happy to try other formats, if they would work.

Comment: @Jens -- I guess it is a duplicate -- and a disappointing answer as well!

Comment: I've been trying to export a 3D model of Mars to Blender and I tried every export file type available and none of them preserved texture data.
  
An alternative for me was to use the Mars entity property called "cylindrical equidistant texture". I exported this to my desktop as mars.jpg and in Blender, the following commands made the planet:

Shift A - Mesh - UV sphere

Shading Mode

Shift A - Search - Image Texture - Open - mars.jpg

Connect the color nodes and there is the model I needed.